# Host a Delphi 7 application process in .net

Tags: .net, delphi

HI!
I'm trying to host a delphi 7 vcl application in a .Net wpf application.
Everything works great except modal dialogs do not behave like modal dialogs, the parent window isn't disabled.
This is my code so far:

```
   class MySimpleDelphiHost : HwndHost
   {
      private Process _appProc;
      public IntPtr hwndHost;

      protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
      {
         _appProc = new Process();
         _appProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
         _appProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"MySimpleDelphiApplication.exe";
         _appProc.Start();
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
         hwndHost = Win32API.FindWindow("TMainForm", null);
         int oldStyle = Win32API.GetWindowLong(hwndHost, Win32API.GWL_STYLE);
         Win32API.SetWindowLong(hwndHost, Win32API.GWL_STYLE, (oldStyle | Win32API.WS_CHILD) & ~Win32API.WS_BORDER);

         Win32API.SetParent(hwndHost, hwndParent.Handle);
         Win32API.ShowWindowAsync(hwndHost, Win32API.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);

         return new HandleRef(this, hwndHost);
      }

      protected override void DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef hwnd)
      {
         _appProc.Kill();         
      }
   }
```

If I host a none delphi application this works just fine. Any ideas?

I created a demo http://www.easy-share.com/1913154119/SimpleDelphiAppHosting.zip . Sorry for the hosting site.

Comment: What do you mean ,You meant parent window of delphi application  or wpf application must be diabled , I think you want to disable form of wpf application.

Comment: hint: adding a .Net tag could be helpful

Comment: If just the parent window of the Delphi application gets disabled then that would be great.

Comment: Is it happening as you like when you run delphi exe normally

Comment: i have posted a answer according to what you said here ; then if you only want to disable the Delphi applications parent window why sooo much of code in c# ; you just have to start the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. 
The VCL TApplication enumerates windows using the EnumThreadWindows function. Because the main form is the Child of my WPF application the EnumThreadWindows doesn't find my mainform. 
To fix this I had to copy the Forms.pas and change TApplication.WndProc procedure. I added this code in the WM_ENABLE case

```
   if TWMEnable(Message).Enabled then
   begin
      if Application.MainForm <> nil then
      begin
         ParentWindow := GetParent(Application.MainForm.Handle);
         if ParentWindow <> 0 then
            EnableWindow(ParentWindow, true);
      end;
      ....
   end else
   begin
     Default;
     if Application.MainForm <> nil then
     begin
       ParentWindow := GetParent(Application.MainForm.Handle);
       if ParentWindow <> 0 then
          EnableWindow(ParentWindow, false);
     end;
     ....
```

There maybe a better solution and I havn't tested this very well, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW have you tried setting:

```
Form.ModalPopupMode = pmExplicit;
Form.ModalParent = ParentForm;
Form.ShowModal;
```

Also you don't have to change tApplication in the Forms unit, you could do

```
var 
  OldWndProc: Pointer; 

function NewWndProc(Handle: hWnd; Msg: UINT; PW: WPARAM; PL: LPARAM): LRESULT stdcall; 
begin
  if Msg = WM_ENABLED then 
  begin
     doWhatever();
     result := 1; // handled
  end else 
  result := CallWindowProc(OldWndProc, Handle, Msg, PW, PL); 
end; 

initialization 
  OldWndProc := Pointer(SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC,    
  LongInt(@NewWndProc)));
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code

`hwndHost = Win32API.FindWindow("TMainForm", null);`

make sure your forms name is not TMainForm (i suspect that) , and you said it worked on other apps so how you identified the names ,

make sure why you used TMainForm

to refer the form named **TMainForm**

or to refer the form named **MainForm**

or to refer the MainForm  // (**Application.mainform**)

Comment: I changed the MainForm to TheMainForm and it doesn't make any difference. I suspect this has something to do with the hidden TApplication window

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the delphi form as a model form of c# app just put delphi form into a delphi dll and call it as a form from c# , and if you also want a stand alone delphi exe (share one form among c# and delphi appps)the call the dll fron Delphi app

but your comment

> *If just the parent window of the
>   Delphi application gets disabled then
>   that would be great.– GunnarIF*

made me think like the following

IF you just want to disable the parent form of Delphi application 
(as you have mentioned in comment for the question )

remove the model form declaration like the above code from the project.dpr (if any)

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2); // form2 is your modal dialogs
```

now

add unit2 to uses list    //unit2 is the unit of modelform

add the following code to the event you want

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
f: TForm  ;
begin
 F  := TForm2.Create(nil);
 f.ShowModal ;

end;
```

don't forget to make property of form2 visible to false (It is on the form2 property inspector) (only if the form is invisible the **showmodel** function will work)

I have posted this answer according to what you have mentioned in the comment of the question its still very hard to identify what is your problem

Comment: @GunnarIF i have posted a answer according to what you as comment  ; then if you only want to disable the Delphi applications parent window why sooo much of code in c# ; you just have to start the process

Comment: if so is this your c# application have user interface

Comment: Thank @Vibeeshan but... I want to display the TheMainForm as a child of my WPF application to control it from the WPF app and when I open a modal dialog in the Delphi app the TheMainForm should be disabled (that is not receive any user input message). I need the TApplication object to process the message queue for the VCL so I have to have it running in a process or in another thread. If I run the Delphi app standalone this works great but if I host the Delphi app process in the WPF app the modal dialog behaves like a modless dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Your code is realy working . The main form inside c# application is disabled when model dialog is showing , but the c# app(now it is just the title bar and the stuff out side the mainform)are not getting disabled  , and you said it worked in other apps , so vcl is a problem i think ,

just now i checked your demo ,  i think it is a problem of VCL (as you said it worked in other development tools) even showmessage function does not disable the main form ;

**The better answer i can predict is**

use DLLs place vcl form inside the dll and call it from c# , it will work

Comment: If you use exe and embedded inside c# app , Delphis vcl could not get what is the mainform(I think that is the problem)